# iOS 9 Orientation Auto-Rotation Animation Not Working, But Always on Main Thread

Tags: ios, swift, animation, screen-rotation

iOS 9.0 (13A340)
Xcode 7.0 (7A220)
OS X 10.10.5 (14F27)

I have a situation where if I rotate the simulator or device (using iPhone 6s sim and iPhone 6+ device), the animation does not also take place. I am unsure of why this is happening. I am not doing anything unusual or crazy with any `UIKit` methods, and I am not calling any method not on the main thread. Additionally, other `UIView` animations I have added appear to work just fine. It is just the rotation that's broken. Other apps seem fine. I'm not sure what I could be doing wrong.

[image: No rotation animation]

Attempts to figure out/solve:

- Used [this extension by Cocoanetics](https://www.cocoanetics.com/2013/02/uiview-background-queue-debugging/) to attempt to see if any `UIKit` execution was not on the main thread.
- Printed out the value of `UIView.areAnimationsEnabled()` during multiple spots in program execution. It always printed `true`.
- Setting `UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)` did not fix.

I am using a custom "nav" view controller (one I made): [SASlideDrawer](https://github.com/ArtisOracle/SASlideDrawer) (Note I am **not** experiencing this same issue with this project alone)

Thank you.

Comment: I also have this problem - curious to see what the solution is.

Comment: Well, I don't know what happened or changed, but this is now fixed...

Comment: Yeah this is the exact same problem I am having... Did you happen to change ur navigation controller stack or window / view controller stack?
I believe I have the same issue or similar : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33213208/ios-device-rotation-instant-snap-rather-than-animation

Comment: Had same issue on device a few times, a hard reboot fixed it

Answer (score 19):

In my case I had target's "Main Interface" set and in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` I have been creating new window and new rootViewController

Comment: This fix worked for me. I don't have a Main Interface because I am manually creating my nav stack in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you. Same issue here. `Main.storyboard` set by default in the Xcode template, but I'm creating my view stack in code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm instantiating my own view controller stack of a navigation controller in app delegate. I fixed the problem by removing the Main interface from the project file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing a similar bug.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6oRq.jpg

The rotation animation occurs for the status bar (which has the clock and the battery icon), but the view itself just changes size, it doesn't do the page flip animation.

This is somewhat repeatable- at first, the rotation occurs correctly, but after I programmatically change the tab view controller index, it can trigger. After it triggers, the rotation animation does not occur for the view until after I reset the app.

Code where I change the tab view controller and then change it back:

```
[appDelegate.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
...code to operate on the code at index 0...
[appDelegate.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];
```

Answer (score 0):

I did change the general setting, and solved this by deleting the Main Interface and Launch Screen File to empty.