# Rotation not animating for view after tabViewController setSelectedIndex

Tags: ios, xcode

The rotation animation occurs for the status bar (which has the clock and the battery icon), but the view itself just changes size, it doesn't do the page flip animation. In the gif (below), I did a few screencaptures of the rotation animation in slow motion. You can see the clock and battery icon rotate into the view, even though the content just scales.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9FGN.jpg

I found some similar, but not quite the same posts:
[iOS Device Rotation Instant Snap rather than animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33213208/ios-device-rotation-instant-snap-rather-than-animation)

[iOS 9 Orientation Auto-Rotation Animation Not Working, But Always on Main Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32848456/ios-9-orientation-auto-rotation-animation-not-working-but-always-on-main-thread/34053006#34053006)

This is somewhat repeatable- at first, the rotation occurs correctly, but after I programmatically change the tab view controller index, it can trigger. After it triggers, the rotation animation does not occur for the view until after I reset the app.

Code where I change the tab view controller and then change it back:

```
[appDelegate.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
...code to operate on the code at index 0...
[appDelegate.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];
```

To emphasize- it DOES animate the rotation correctly when I first run the app. Behaves the same in simulator and in hardware. IOS9. Xcode 7.1.1.

Anyone know why a viewcontroller's content would stop animating during rotation?

edit-

---

To answer fragilecat's questions:

1) I am set up to use the rotation functions, as described in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIViewController/attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation

I have implemented shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation and shouldAutorotate and supportedInterfaceOrientations. The supportedInterfaceOrientations gets called once, when the viewcontroller loads. shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation and shouldAutorotate are apparently never called.

2) I am receiving size change messages via viewWillTransitionToSize- this is ios9 so there aren't any rotation messages. willTransitionToTraitCollection is apparently never called, though it is overriden. I am calling the super for both.

3) I am not using viewWillLayoutSubviews() or viewDidLayoutSubviews(). I am only overriding viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear. These do not affect rotation.

4) I am not dynamically changing rotation methods.

What I did notice, is that rotation works at first, but then fails (doesn't rotate but just scales), after I change the tabBarViewController selectedViewController programmatically after the use clicks "ok" to an alertview.  I haven't figured out why yet, but it is repeatably after that event.

Sequence of the bug:

1. Works fine, rotates ok.
2. User hits "ok" to an alertview
3. I programmatically call [tabBarViewController setSelectedIndex:0]
4. I call some functions on the viewcontroller at index 0.
5. I programmatically call [tabBarViewController setSelectedIndex:2] (back to the original)
6. rotation now does not occur reliably

Comment: I think somewhere you are doing `[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO]`. Search for "AnimationsEnabled" string in the project.

Comment: I made a demo project and I can reproduce this situation. I think my previous comment is the answer.

Comment: I am definitely not calling setAnimationsEnabled:NO at any point in the code. That WOULD cause this effect, but I'm not doing it.

Answer (score 3):

**Anyone know why a viewcontroller's content would stop animating during rotation?**

1. The child view controller's rotation method's are configure incorrectly.
2. Your child view controller's are not receiving rotation messages.
3. You have custom code in the view controller's layout methods.
4. Your code is dynamically altering rotation/layout/animation methods.

**I am looking for direction on what kind of bugs can produce this type of error.**

This is some what hard to answer with out seeing your code, but here are the steps I would take in trouble shooting this issue.

1. Confirm that your child view controllers are correctly setup for rotation.

[UIViewController Rotation Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIViewController/attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation)

2. Confirm that your child view controller's are receiving the following messages so that you can rule out this as the issue as this is how rotation is handled in iOS 9.

   func willTransitionToTraitCollection(_ newCollection: UITraitCollection,
          withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)

   func viewWillTransitionToSize(_ size: CGSize,
   withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)

If you are overriding these methods else where you should make sure you call the super's version, see [UIContentContainer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIContentContainer_Ref/) for details.

3. Comment out any custom code that you *might* have in [`viewWillLayoutSubviews()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillLayoutSubviews) implementation of your view controllers. Also you can check your frames between [`viewWillLayoutSubviews()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillLayoutSubviews) and [`viewDidLayoutSubviews()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLayoutSubviews).

### **EDIT**

You need to execute the tab change on the main thread. If I am correct you are using the delegate of UIAlertView? I don't think your on the main thread went you make your call!

```
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [appDelegate.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
    });
```

Comment: See my edited answer. Even though I still haven't figured it out, I granted the bounty as thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: In this case I would build a quick test app with the child view controller's only having their own views  and the bear minimum to carry out your button logic and see if you generate the bug.

Comment: @arinmorf please let me know your results of doing this.

Comment: I just verified that alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
  IS called on the main thread. Good idea though.

Comment: No, you have the delegate set on UIAlertView, right?

Comment: So in the method  (UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex do you call [appDelegate.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0] in it on it's own? To see if this is actually the issue if you do not press the alert view button does the rotation work correctly?

Comment: Can you post the code for  (UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex?