# All controllers rotate without animation in ios

Tags: ios, animation, viewcontroller, autorotate

All my controllers rotate without animation. Can not fix it. I did not overrided `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` and `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` methods. How can I fix it?

Comment: Add more information to your question, Maybe an example (image, gif), or some code snippet.

Comment: check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32848456/ios-9-orientation-auto-rotation-animation-not-working-but-always-on-main-thread